# Am I calling Spotify API's method for audio analysis correctly?

Tags: python, api, spotify

Why does my API call give a long output with multiple repetitions, is it the intended outcome of my code or am I doing something wrongly?

(1) Following is the method I used to call the audio_analysis method as in the documentation.

```
analysis = sp.audio_analysis('Your_Track_ID_Here')
print(analysis)
```

(2) Previously, I faced issues with "iopub data rate exceeded". I had changed the configuration and only tried with 1 song id in the parameter, the issue was eventually resolved.

Yet, the output is still extremely long even for the analysis for a single song. I wonder what I did wrong.

(3) I previously tried out the audio_features method in the API and the output is perfect like this:

```
    [{'danceability': 0.674, 'energy': 0.618, 'key': 8, 'loudness': -7.368, 'mode': 1, 'speechiness': 0.0241, 'acousticness': 0.932, 'instrumentalness': 0, 'liveness': 0.132, 'valence': 0.331, 'tempo': 100.015, 'type': 'audio_features', 'id': '1atjghnkmdsiexphBSF4Yc', 'uri': 'spotify:track:1atjghnkmdsiexphBSF4Yc', 'track_href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/1atjghnkmdsiexphBSF4Yc', 'analysis_url': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/1atjghnkmdsiexphBSF4Yc', 'duration_ms': 191975, 'time_signature': 4}])
```

However, after I used the audio analysis method. The output was okay until this part, which spans multiple lines long.

```
"codestring":eJxdmgu2KykOBLfiJfBH7H9jL0LY167Xc3r6gl0UoFQqE3x2r7FPG6_yqrWVc0YfrxZBq7YZs8Vr7vU6-b264xWLz0errcXkW2M3mnWUOHy1lSjvZuv81Vf8NhfjRjl71cJT_JfRohf-Wa_eGHicOqPOul89GJhPdymHp8Zg4Ki1nz1tbga2OepyhiU-zbn7a_Yc-ZTa26S5PiO3VvtrtcfIzOl35F0fI-9B35wsvu392puB2y4z1mqHpTDwjBNjFsboYasch_b9vub0M0ct48XuFHfxzDrZijN5zVkn-uwj_8oZ8_LS24t5RX657U5o2K3iPu7OShaBKr1nSHpjDYv2cCJtth6zbNrbqcxFAH2SUDoDHm-VBdHuq9wg9haN9voLm1GsNdf5FzdiPX0Lz4OMzheamNirVJfLR01UDNa0m1iqHSi55XXzVl7AKonwmSAt6nk5cAFXzp4v1pHrWe5WHObPSBmTweZtQWaMFg83-miz3eFwIGgQ4DrFztlj1r4Pw0-j1hl7jWiT9umuJ0YlanUxXQHQWu8-vQDXGwGslLbg4ulaCLxt9yRqYZCyeH4Lr91KZR6L0bf4ArVjrB1-Hs3dH_6zeH4fowGwxvR1If4qs-nL9Kjh_7N0QLz8erhYFtY60GL4U0Yih1FJR9oilMWWdszOekYb7_bO9mwGkz05w-AfgwkEeoRRAzIJlsEKwTNtcWs-9F7M_QJOmG7vmwmZ0uc0AcpqKjAANCaMWN1r8qY639u1mArfr5GQ5R_2ne-DOd6_K805Jm3BCvLCWNverMqdDODcaZ-alLLWZu1wSGG_xgEq4KfKKSPe-dvz8yiZQABtyk1MJS54wL8jtfiE04xmZwzfKCsgr21a8f29WHywdGGSDFckEBiuzeJ6GrGHGvl8VvYLmLGhpTGf6X6MFQMokmZtSom8_-yoPL6EOlglmYEDbbG-WXN00dKWyw9G3pO0hl2amGtz8siybTiByymd0NKWGCVndrTz-qSdNz0f27wQyhulz-X2xE64kLunD6Z3RC9EUtgohj8L6pqTUcM4XQyRNHsPtvDVi729tH3Yoci_iBZfquF0ehGDfQ5WmwstUddrEETiGjxZE61Bm3k32i6nkwgbNB7aUs-E9APwVNqiFVosLIPtAxLL3V7Qog-SFIAB4A430qKR4GC3wS5VowlW2YkRXvCjqcTgzIdhetIQgwOUAm3B8RYK8_iMyWSGvGmlIGqT0Wb5lgrfNtejVvR5HsWCPf6tFn2JNHiGRDnHdlya2sTAvdoiSS6F5Ald3yIHZDItco32TGagfhzohTapTYEi9Bsk9dxwI8-AziaJJIkgKD60p4lboEDe1KyoPM7MC_XBvTxv1ixsdiQ9t_JHJOwGf7IbQ_Ku-f2TxADtsDF8UmpWEfgQTrEt0vicvSHTXmaQvR3GIGdeLCN3h-nIFLTF4xZYO8tFlUcbOC2Eyc9drokv9KugMtamLcnCeC0ggkW6dHlpdKqaNE2iU-9or8tThdf3w0IslV8ZIFs_FEbm8Y_EmMlrc1Jz2B_aFmUTl0QfjLcyM8A3ucLHy-QnMBb648eJpeJiO7RCaIsSizJRT2za7P8LpQMrSfOw0FDmTGfv7m13n-hS06AS2mKNvn6qcbeYpQaIkoRDbeD7YEPm7Xw_LtjAYtBzUc1ymlWPEj6kF943KBL1uM9btMDKDACvUGIZnz2gJgnTmRqEwrwgBmgbsrJ4WSKJY-OrKUKW4aJwbdqp79A7rMjPFRsJIuoM8UEHiX4odzB_BmzCaSEqWTPfZJ8jpz1UO0t5436zYwRq2L5lei7nyHgwoUqDYku2sYBeMkWJo4_STlXI5iEqjiJx3flu1MIBmD5pANB3EvMcyXQso0PJbMDIdKJu9u7MeGo4PuVtKgZnihLmW4icz0-Zb1BWjjmhIJju0p7g2p21bBGtqBkPGSmzEdJy4-aS1wEx2wdZvkQJvX6b5XXFE2XJ6FCKjmk34pIBrKTcMJzQxIDYqZoQvLtBpu7jPKdZ5Pdli8Zw8SMhTdMki4RjAmeerMII3V6OFUMxxPiQykh5c8w2osNkRn4eo2SdYIZU_ZnkIVzAinhfspQoLwCZCS8JH-YmjaYt0Ys0phrACC92IZl58TKr2lJhCh5VDGXKXCwGHzRMgrHSiLDDajM4ODUIzSr65AxDQ604iC7mksbEItUzlNA42AcGUIOKcKU36ZZKZs_3u6Fkx9wlZ9svlM1cxA8D9Eud1FU1PG1o-I0l1f8a9YElFGhiCdzDtnx_uBmZnPTYfvsdkEUqrPQ7k8_gALZ5mTuaINbp0-l_mBtAaX5boFNb0LHuyjI2WVZUtrSXavtaE0JDWwF6maSm7r6C88Mka19B-TGLK8qDaVYqkq9FXOmEvu6Cl45fV7jSC_2249cm7lQgX5-4k2e-RnHX8uDxXdd_hu5ZpHeamTevUwd28grBZ_cwFK-dXuaKAvD1cl2_ooCUeYiCnV7m532j_-cg18NCjvPwkDu9C4NACCYWgEobWQFZd7kz_nwkTKUxuNEp6KGpcE1okEVHa7eTJpgJMpQRKEiW1gxm1SoRuluG9PZsNrHUP6cbUM2jSxzFNTEwuw-eraLAhaJre17riPTN16dbucELV5s88Q3mTrfy256zvUUCRoB2ggmkuQXse7qTA4WjEbJttHwfmgSBF-lWrhuQ5Z3mFXzSQKQ3UWyjCDIKqaC0brCCf0kTmm2wxW7ABylsIABKEqOlN0kjqZqhLQt-jWT0u7prJKNbwu_b4NtXXMXxfVv_Iq_6-ajX1r6PKXAMpK1zV5kz-nUmS1iH46cTYa1DFmV201haLwOaYLWQZbv60Br-UlC3TyJnzhhLwo4CrUL26kMIPEtnMnOSDtF1OtvCYEloKX3A3V9JIBNfcl17G8WQ_1KhfI1iuPtvPTh8X4y_PAeMtPcDCgFSgSIFbFlVxLh6kNluzwFoeyiC8xlGfqJkXU6HjhR8ttvV_kVeA_R5KnITk7JFWxb_GsNTUyCmcT0esnisoEBphtPPdxpDSdwKfdJ6hHIbacf7kjiwZcpZD3Tevpnp3o_TiixrbtbitCI8zmy2w_WPT7SUd9oKMIo3y0N1vZQZqS8Rji7_jI--pJgx25EFGrYCW-gzHpvpE3v6-Ne5XsVjBKhqeMB0BcGxhDO91BtX3S99QHoXgqfJdfWrXvBoMtydNC_sID4XfXCSZqYIa-36bWdbnD_qRPY34oxBaCSgcQ8tiCRKhL9uLLulszCblCfMaKUpOKHYhIORLrmYoLZpHcAthElbqLJxENWGs490lFYC0vF1J6ecrpHV0_ZMRGHE036SrJMenRHZvBMf21g985B_zsdbzJ0d0iybPe4BXLkFGJaGqFQe9e-MkWBnx_OUkdL1PGesCp7fQqF9f1QKp_JbKmiLyMUc-BeImedvBwkfqHbLEIRYC4iqzHsSyFsBeNU55yMe53iaBL5bfiPTLs_46FOTtfiUhJaqKtPfWAOdXFsqhqpeIKCeP65W3pIAQnV_UkPg3FAvSG479uV5CDpZqOx3IfChPMNMw_O1i3SIyK9f9N1t_BjGWtLjeNigOHaMNDn8qaG3zl2x6jlUuWd5QF9bhlxFved-HEtA06mzTJd_hP-1me3kI2f--kwzWCxgEtBteXya3oedProytVAaatGSUXFeJeFMIEt-fj4HDbDnPVtfv6JCX_g-hbuqotb2PPGWhh5-lE_Kw5D........."
```

There are also multiple repetitions of several variables such as duration, confidence, loudness, pitch etc. which spans several pages long (for a single song).

The minimal reproducible code for my output is the following:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
cid ="Your_id_here" 
secret = "Your_secret_key_here"
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, 
client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
analysis = sp.audio_analysis('YOUR_TRACK_ID_HERE')
print(analysis)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @MofX, I added a minimal, reproducible example. Is that alright? I'm new here and welcome feedback. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Get Audio Analysis for a Track](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-tracks) API and what I know of the API myself the "codestring" is a valid part of the response object for this API, but if you don't need it you could ignore its value - in my own C# I've done before I just ignore the value.

If you use the API Console there you should find that part of the JSON is returned.

If you however need the value I think it is a base-64 encoded value of something but may need to get more in-depth information if you need that value but it may be just another representation of the Bars, Tatums etc returned in the rest of the call

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I noticed that several output variables such as start, duration, confidence, loudness_max, loudness_max_time':, 'loudness_max':, 'pitches':, 'timbre':, etc. kept repeating themselves, spanning multiple pages long to the point where it is incomprehensible. Do you think there could be something wrong with the way I wrote the code?

Comment: Could be the library is concatenating the results, I've not used the python library for this so can't be sure